# graph product that commutes with automorphism, and semi direct

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Is there a way to construct a "product" of graphs $G\rtimes H$ such that $Aut(G \rtimes H ) \simeq Aut(G) \rtimes Aut(H) $? A related topic is ["Semidirect product" of graphs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84317/semidirect-product-of-graphs) but not quite the same.

Comment: What action of the group $\text{Aut}(H)$ on the group $\text{Aut}(G)$ did you have in mind for defining their semidirect product?

Comment: Any abstract action, the semi direct product of the graphs will depend on this action.

Comment: For example if I want to find a graph with automorphism group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_9$ I don't have to follow Frucht's construction instead I can use this method. And contraction of graphs with automorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is easier.

Comment: Do you mean the group product? What type of product do you mean?

Comment: Given an action of $ Aut(H )$ on $ Aut(G)$ I want a product to be defined on the two graphs $G$ and $H$ such that the automorphism group of this product is the semidirect product of the automorhpism groups of $G$ and $H$ under the action.